# Creating a link to open a terminal with a ruby executable

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I came across one situation in ruby, cucumber.
I want to create a link in ruby which will print on a HTML in cucumber report, when I click on that link then it should open a terminal with ruby script execution.

is it possible?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I am comparing two files using `icdiff` which shows diff in colors but when I print the exact result on HTML report it is not showing colors which displayed in terminal.

Comment: Wouldn't running a terminal be over kill though? plus there is no guarantee that the user will have colors set for their terminal and the diff may end up being the same color

Comment: Your question is changing. Please don't do that, especially in comments.

Comment: Don't do that. Cucumber isn't CI. Cucumber runs in CI. CI should be handling the cucumber report, not cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call: ruby your_program.rb

or

- start your program with #!/usr/bin/env ruby, make your file
- executable by running chmod +x your_program.rb and do
- ./your_program.rb some_param